# What does getProjectTriggers() return when running from an GDocs add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, add-on

The documentation for getProjectTriggers (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getProjectTriggers()) says "Gets all installable triggers associated with the current project." What does this mean if we use this method as an add-on? Will it return the current users triggers in the current document, in all documents, or triggers for this add-on for all users?

We're trying to adhere to the restriction that add-ons can have max one time-based trigger per user per document, so would need to know if we can use this method for checking if a trigger has already been set in the current document.

Comment: Is there some reason that you haven't tried it yourself? That would seem to be the most straight-forward way to answer your own question.